# My App Crashed when trying to get Contents Of URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web, nsstring

my app crashed when nsstring getting contents of URL.

```
website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hidden."]; 
contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

the crash log is:

```
void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x865cc40: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.
2012-07-10 11:15:17.654 MyApplication[1505:19407] OK // some output
2012-07-10 11:15:17.660 MyApplication[1505:19407] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x865cc40: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UITextRangeImpl isEmpty]
3   -[UITextRange(UITextSelectionAdditions) _isCaret]
4   -[UITextSelectionView setCaretBlinks:]
5   -[UIKeyboardImpl setCaretBlinks:]
6   -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]
7   -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:]
8   -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
9   -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews]
10  -[UIResponder(Internal) _windowBecameKey]
11  -[UITextField _windowBecameKey]
12  -[UIWindow makeKeyWindow]
13  -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible]
14  -[MyApplicationAppDelegate checkLogin]
15  -[NSThread main]
16  __NSThread__main__
17  _pthread_start
18  thread_start
```

the code is called with `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(checkLogin) withObject:nil];` from `IBAction`. what i am doing wrong?

(Xcode 4.3, Mac OS X Lion, iPhone Simulator 5.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that error message, you're trying to update a `UIKit` object from a background thread, and the UI can only be updated from the main thread.

Instead, use `self performSelectorOnMainThread` to call back to the main thread to update your UI with whatever information you received when your web call returns.

From your main thread:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(checkLogin) withObject:nil];
```

In the background:

```
- (void)checkLogin {
    // Do web stuff
    ...

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) 
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)updateUI {
    [statusLabel setText:@"Done!"];
}
```

Comment: but - how to run it in the background?

Comment: You can still run your web code in the background using `performSelectorInBackground`. When the selector running in the background completes, call `performSelectorOnMainThread` from the background thread to update the UI.

Comment: in checkLogin do `[self webStuffDone];` at the end?

Comment: and if i want to do it at the start of method?

Comment: The same. If you're in a background thread, just call `performSelectorOnMainThread` with a selector that manipulates your UI whenever you need to update your interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
      - (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject.
```

Comment: but - how to run it in the background?

Comment: what I feel best is use GCD or you can use another thread also.

Comment: dispatch_queue_t getdata = dispatch_queue_create(“any string”, NULL);
    dispatch_async(getdata, ^{ 
// Code here 
});